# Databasedotcom gem and dbdc_controller error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, databasedotcom-gem

I've attempted to deploy the dbdc_controller project (https://github.com/dburkes/dbdc_controller) to Heroku, and am getting an error when pulling up the index page for users:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

The logs simply show "ArgumentError (ArgumentError)" with no specific error.  Has anyone else encountered something like this?

Comment: Can you provide the backtrace as well? Does it work locally?